# Random EOFException error

Tags: java, sockets, io, file-transfer

I'm currently building some networking application. 
One of the methods `ANDgate()` uses sockets to transfer some bytes. 
Client side

```
public static ArrayList ANDgate(ArrayList bits, ArrayList macs, ArrayList tags, int gateNumber) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Socket s= new Socket("192.168.1.109", 8888);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    //Some computation

    oos.writeByte(p);
    oos.flush();
    oos.writeByte(p1);
    oos.flush();

    //Some computation        
    byte P = ios.readByte();
    byte P1 = ios.readByte();

    //Some computation
    oos.writeByte(p_shared1);
    oos.flush();

    //Some computation      
    byte p_shared2 = ios.readByte();

    //Some computation      
    oos.writeByte(p1_shared2);
    oos.flush();        
    //Some computation      
    oos.close();
    ios.close();
    s.close();

}
```

On the server side I have pretty much the same code.
While running a program this method can be called and executed successfully 1000 times(or more), but randomly appears the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Gate.ANDgate(Gate.java:119)
```

119 line is this `ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());`

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: Is it possible the `ServerSocket` closes the connection right away?

Comment: Nope. Server closes socket and all streams in the same place as client, after all network actions. This method crushed at random call.